# Queue in webbrowser on top of database?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, data-synchronization, pouchdb

In a web application the user is able to perform some tasks I need to send to the server asynchronously. Basically, this is really easy, but now I would like it to be also working fine in offline-mode.

My idea is to use a client-side queue, and transfer elements from that queue to the server if the network connection is available.

I could use [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/), but I don't need all the tasks on the client-side, so I don't want a full client-side database with all the elements the server has as well. I only need some kind of queue: Put it in there, and try to send it to the server: If it worked, dequeue, otherwise try again after a short pause.

How could I implement this? Is there something such as RabbitMQ (conceptually!) available for browsers? A queue on top of the browsers' built-in database? Something like that?

Or can this issue be solved using PouchDB?

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB does support one-way replication (just do `clientDb.replicate.to("http://server/")`), so if you are already running CouchDB on your server, it might be a quick & easy way to implement a queueing of tasks type of system.

You will probably want to use a filter on your replication, because when you "dequeue" or delete a task from the client side db, you probably don't want to replicate that delete to the server :) This answer is specific to CouchDB, but it should work in PouchDB too, as I think PouchDB does support filtered replication: [CouchDB replicate without deleting documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3890497/223594).

That said, using PouchDB like this seems a little awkward, and the full replication system might be a little more overhead than is necessary for a simple queueing of tasks. Depends on what the needs of your app are though, and the exact nature of the tasks you are queueing! It could be as simple as an array that you `push` tasks into, and periodically check if there are tasks in there, which you can `pop` or `shift` off the array and send to the server.

There's also [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue), which is commonly used in node.js but also works in the browser (this queue is not backed by any type of storage, but you could add persistent storage using PouchDB or another client-side db).